# How to measure time taken to run SCPI commands?

Tags: measurements, computer-engineering, computer-hardware

We all know that every program takes time to run. Normally in Python, the time built-in Python library would be sufficient to measure time-taken to run code. How may I determine how long a SCPI (Standard Commands for Programmable Instruments) command takes to run?

The computer hardware platform is Microsoft Windows. The measurement instrument is Agilent 34401a DMM. The serial communication protocol is RS232.

Comment: Can you tell us more about the instrument? Based on my experience SCPI is related to IEEE-488 or GPIB (or similar). If you are using GPIB then the round trip time may be sed on the instrument. Can you add some details, such hardware platform and OS.

Comment: Looks like the post is abandon by the author. I have updated the post to align with the forum guidelines.